# How to Fix Errors while conducting a Permutation Test

Tags: r

I am new to R.  I would like to use a permutation test to see a relationship between y and x1. In this case, I want y is fixed, whereas x1 is permuted and the other regressor, x2, is constant. 
Because I have a longitudinal dataset and my dependent variable, y, is count data, I use a fixed-effect

I run the following code

```
setwd("D:/trial")
getwd()

trial <- read.csv("trial.csv")

b <- c()
r <- c()

data = trial[,c(-1,-6)]
for(i in 1:500){
    data$x1 <- sample(data$x1)
    placebo <- glm(y ~ data$x1 + x2+ as.factor(code) + as.factor(year), 
    data=data, family=poisson)
    b <- append(b, placebo$coef[4])
    r <- append(r,cor(data$x1, data$y))
    coef(summary(placebo))
}
hist(b)
```

and got an error message as:

> Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'x2' not found
>       hist(b) Error in hist.default(b) : 'x' must be numeric

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Why don't you define "x2" as you did "data$x1"?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about that but maybe you should replace x2 by data$x2 and then convert your b to a numeric value like this :

```
hist(as.numeric(b))
```

Comment: Arkning, thanks for your advice! I tried it. However, I still get errors, as follows:    Error in model.frame.default(formula = y ~ data$x1 + data$x2 + as.factor(code) +  : 
  invalid type (NULL) for variable 'data$x2'
> hist(as.numeric(b))
Error in hist.default(as.numeric(b)) : invalid number of 'breaks'